# Jest can't get the Prisma Service but he is defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, prisma

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydM80.png)

```
FAIL  src/urls/service/urls.service.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'src/prismaService/prisma.service' from 'urls/service/urls.service.ts'

    Require stack:
      urls/service/urls.service.ts
      urls/service/urls.service.spec.ts

      1 | import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
      2 | import { isValidUrl } from '../utils/isValidUrl';
    > 3 | import { PrismaService } from 'src/prismaService/prisma.service';
        | ^
      4 | import { NewUrl } from '../utils/NewUrlType';
      5 | import { Urls } from '@prisma/client';
      6 | import { UpdatedUrl } from '../utils/updatedUrl';

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (urls/service/urls.service.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (urls/service/urls.service.spec.ts:2:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.287 s
Ran all test suites matching /urls\/service\/urls.service.spec.ts/i.
```

I use prisma and nestJs but i can't test with Jest because he gives me the prisma services
can't find it

Comment: Have you solved it? I got ````TypeError: client_1.PrismaClient is not a constructor``` when importing Prisma client in a suit jest test